# Bracket on shutter speed with auto ISO

Tags: camera-settings, shutter-speed, bracketing, auto-iso

I have my camera on manual mode, with auto ISO, and I would like to bracket 3 photos changing shutter speed (keeping the same ISO for all 3 shots). Can I do that on auto ISO?

I'm using a Canon EOS Rebel SL3.

Note: I know it doesn't make sense at first, "why use auto ISO if you don't want it to change?", but I'm trying to save some time, by having the camera pick the ISO for me, for the first "reference" shot, and then bracket the other two with the shutter speed (instead of ISO).
This is because (I believe) it doesn't make much sense to bracket with ISO, since i'll capture the same information (same light), just boosting the signal.

Answer (score 0):

To do bracketing with your camera you can use already defined way in the firmware. You can find the below text on page 162 of camera [manual](https://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/2/0300034502/01/eosrebelsl3-eos200d2-ug-en.pdf).

> 1. Select [Expo.comp./AEB].
>
> - Under the [camera] tab, select [Expo. comp./AEB], then press <0>.
>
> 2. Set the AEB range.
>
> - Turn the  dial to set the AEB range (1).
> - Press the   keys to set the exposure compensation amount. If AEB is combined with exposure compensation, AEB will be
>   applied centering on level of exposure compensation.
> - Press  to set it.
>   When you press the shutter button halfway, the AEB range will be displayed in the viewfinder.
>
> 3. Take the picture.
>
> - Focus and press the shutter button completely, and the shots will be taken in the sequence of standard exposure, decreased exposure, and
>   increased exposure

If this do not work in M mode you can set temporary you camera to Av and use above procedure.

or set temporary ISO to static value , set speed, aperture, take a shot, change aperture/speed, take a shot, change aperture/speed, take a shot. And then return to auto ISO

Comment: this will bracket with ISO, my question is precisely about if I can change this behavior

Comment: @LucasNoetzold, IMHO no, I did this on my camera and it work fine. Just test it